# Maximum/Minimum value of a function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Find the Maximum and Minimum of  $f(x)=x^3-x^2-8x+1 $ on $[-2,2]$

I take the first derivative which is: $f'(x)=3x^2-2x-8$

Since I am unable to determine the critical points from the first derivative, do I take the second derivative to find the critical points?

Comment: Why would you be unable to determine the critical points from the first derivative?

Comment: I suppose I just don't know how to determine them

Comment: Well, what's wrong with solving $f'(x)=0$?  It's just a quadratic.

Comment: Note:  regardless of the above, don't forget to compute $f(\pm 2)$ to compare.  It is perfectly possible for one or the other extreme value to occur at an endpoint.

Comment: Can I ask why you chose to set f'(x)=0? Where does that come from

Comment: I assumed you knew what a critical point was...that's the definition.

Comment: For a function with continuous derivatives, like this, the extreme values will either occur at an endpoints or at points where $f'(x)=0$.  If the derivative failed to exist at some points (as happens, say, with $F(x)=|x|$) then you'd have to test those points as well.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing this up for me lulu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just because you are doing calculus doesn't mean you can forget all your precalculus!
$$
3x^2-2x-8=0\implies (3x+4)(x-2)=0
$$
Which will yield the critical points. Again, don't forget to check end points!

edit: from comments, I realize the above may be unclear. For a function you can differentiate on a interval which includes its endpoints, maxima and minima occur when the derivative is zero (think about what a horizontal tangent line looks like) or at end points.

Comment: I forgot precalc.. forgot I could factor like that, thank you! will best answer you in 5 minutes

Comment: @QuestionQuestion no problem! Good luck!

Comment: @qbert Your factorization is wrong. In fact $$3x^2-2x-8=(x-2)(3x+4)$$

Comment: @MercyKing oops, looks like I forgot precalculus, fixing